# How to refer to a nested type of a templated base class

Tags: c++

I have the following structure of base and derived class:

```
template<class T>
class Base {
public:
  Base();
  
protected:
  struct Foo{
    int a;
    int b;
  };
  int c;
};

template<class T>
class Derived : Base<T> {
public:
  Derived();
...
};
```

I now want to access the protected part of the base class within the derived class. For `c` or any other non-type member one can use `this->c` or `Base<T>::c`. But how can I construct an instance of Foo for example? `this->Foo{x,y}` or `Base<T>::Foo{x,y}` do not work, at least not with g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [dependent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) types you need to use `typename` keyword to indicate that the name refers to a type.

```
template <class T>
class Derived : Base<T> {
public:
  Derived() : foo{1, 2} {}

  typename Base<T>::Foo foo;
};
```